# Pomodoro JavaFX (MVC Pattern) Countdown Timer

Tags: mvc, javafx

I made a simple JavaFX app. It is just a Pomodoro timer, it works as expected.

The Pomodoro study pattern is a technique where you study for 25 minutes and take a 5-minute break and after 4 periods of this, you get a longer 15-minute break (and then repeat the whole thing). I made a simple countdown timer that keeps track of which study session you are on.

[image: Here is what the view looks like]

I am just wondering if I implemented the MVC pattern correctly. The Main class seems a bit redundant to me. Are there any other improvements I could make to the code?

Thanks

```
public class Controller {

    public Controller(Model model, View view) {
        view.getStartPauseBtn().setOnAction((e) -> {
            if (model.isRunning()) {
                model.pauseTimer();
                model.setRunning(false);
            } else {
                model.startTimer();
                model.setRunning(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Model {

    private boolean isRunning = false;
    private boolean isBreak = false;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private int counter = 60 * 25; // 60 * 25 Testing:10
    private final Label timerLbl, studySessionLbl, whatsNextLbl;
    private int seconds, minutes, studySessionNum =0;

    public Model(Label timerLbl, Label studySessionLbl, Label whatsNextLbl) {
        this.timerLbl = timerLbl;
        this.studySessionLbl = studySessionLbl;
        this. whatsNextLbl = whatsNextLbl;
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        isRunning = running;
    }

    public void pauseTimer() {
        timer.cancel();
    }

    public void startTimer() {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    counter--;

                    seconds = counter % 60;
                    minutes = counter / 60;
                    if (seconds < 10 && minutes < 10) {
                        timerLbl.setText("0" + minutes + ":0" + seconds);
                    } else if (minutes < 10) {
                        timerLbl.setText("0" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
                    } else {
                        timerLbl.setText(minutes + ":" + seconds);
                    }

                    if (counter == 0 && studySessionNum == 4 && !isBreak) { // long break
                        isBreak = true;
                        counter = 15 * 60; // 15 * 60 Testing: 5
                        studySessionNum = 0;
                    } else if (counter == 0 && !isBreak) { // short break
                        counter = 5 * 60; // 5 * 60 Testing: 2
                        isBreak = true;
                    } else if (counter == 0) { // break finished
                        counter = 25 * 60; // 25 * 60 Testing: 10
                        studySessionNum++;
                        isBreak = false;
                    }

                    // update labels
                    studySessionLbl.setText("Study session number: " + studySessionNum);
                    if (isBreak) {
                        whatsNextLbl.setText("Next: Study session (25 minutes)");
                    } else if (studySessionNum == 4) {
                        whatsNextLbl.setText("Next: Long study break (15 minutes)");
                    } else {
                        whatsNextLbl.setText("Next: Short study break (5 minutes)");
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }

}
```

```
Main class:

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Pomodoro extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        View view = new View();
        Model model = new Model(view.getTimerLbl(), view.getStudySessionNumLbl(), view.getWhatsNextLbL());
        new Controller(model, view);
        stage.setTitle("Pomodoro Timer");
        stage.setScene(view.getScene());
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I did not use a fxml file for the view.

```
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;

public class View {

    private final Label studySessionNumLbl, whatsNextLbL, timerLbl;
    private final Button startPauseBtn;
    private final Scene scene;

    // UI Setup
    public View() {
        studySessionNumLbl = new Label();
        whatsNextLbL = new Label();
        HBox hbox = new HBox(studySessionNumLbl, whatsNextLbL);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hbox.setSpacing(10);

        timerLbl = new Label("25:00");
        timerLbl.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", FontWeight.BOLD, 70));
        startPauseBtn = new Button("> ||");
        VBox vbox = new VBox(timerLbl, startPauseBtn, hbox);
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vbox.setSpacing(20);

        scene = new Scene(vbox, 400, 400);

    }

    public Scene getScene() {
        return scene;
    }

    public Label getStudySessionNumLbl() {
        return studySessionNumLbl;
    }

    public Label getWhatsNextLbL() {
        return whatsNextLbL;
    }

    public Button getStartPauseBtn() {
        return startPauseBtn;
    }

    public Label getTimerLbl() {
        return timerLbl;
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not going to write an answer, but `Timer` is not a good choice in `JavaFX`. You should use `Timeline` or something else from the `Animation` API. Here are a few examples you can have a look at. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766244/creating-a-timer-that-shows-the-time-in-hhmmss-format-javafx/50774740#50774740) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50626831/how-to-set-up-two-timelines-to-one-app/50627639#50627639).